# Samsung 970 EVO 500GB NVMe PCIe M.2 & Asus H170 Pro Gaming Motherboard

Tags: motherboard

Can I use a Samsung 970 EVO 500GB NVMe PCIe M.2 2280 SSD in an Asus H170 Pro Gaming Motherboard? The user guide seems to be unclear. If so, will I get full speeds of the SSD or will they be limited?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

M.2 is the socket for NVMe SSDs, 2280 indicates the physical size of the SSD (your board must support it so screws align).

[Your board](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/H170-PRO-GAMING/specifications/) has this matching storage option: `1 x M.2 Socket 3, with M Key, type 2242/2260/2280/22110 storage devices support (both SATA & PCIE mode)`.

You're going to get full speed as M.2 Socket 3 (fits M-Key pins) [uses 4x PCIe lanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying) which is the maximum for NVMe SSDs currently, and the [970 EVO specs](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evo/) also indicate it uses 4x PCIe lanes (and therefore is M-keyed).

Answer (score -1):

NVMe is not sata III .the manual for the h170-pro says nothing about the NVMe being compatible with the h170-pro board only sata III. so far that i know asus has no updated drivers for the m.2 NVMe ssd

Comment: Sorry, as per the first answer to my question it worked without a flaw... read/write full speeds tested where they should be. Operational since Sept. 2018.